# Is there any difference in meaning between "We tried to get him to come to church" and "We tried to get him coming to church"?

Tags: infinitives, present-participles

I heard that 'sb1 gets sb2 to do sth' means the doer (sb1) causes the recipient (sb2) to do something one time while 'sb1 gets sb2 to do sth' means the doer causes the recipient to do something regularly.

According to this, "We tried to get him to come to church" means 'we' tried to cause him to come to church once, but "We tried to get him coming to church" means 'we' tried to cause him to come to church on Sundays.

Does this distinction make sense? Or is it partially true and partially false, or entirely wrong?

Comment: That is how I would interpret your example: once versus habitually.

Comment: Well, the second is what a hit man would say when he missed his target, as said target was on his way to worship.

Comment: Assuming that the grammatical distinction mentioned in this post is agreed, I guess that the distinction doesn't hold for my example since the verb 'get' is more likely to be read as 'strike' rather than 'cause' in the second sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Try to get pronoun verb-ing" (66 instances in GloWbE) is **much** less common than "Try to get pronoun to verb" (797 instances); if you remove examples with "it" for the pronoun, the numbers are 33 and 689.

"We tried to get him coming to church" could make sense in context, but to me it seems so unlikely that the interpretation that first occurred to me is a quite different meaning of "get him": "We tried to attack him [when he was] coming to church". Interestingly "We tried to get him going to church" would also be awkward for me in that sense, but not quite as much as with "coming": I'm not sure why.

Comment: "going" is awkward to me because if you're waiting to ambush him, he's likely coming in your direction. "Going" sounds like you might be behind him and have to catch up to him before attacking.

Comment: I meant that "going" was less awkward in the OP's sense than "coming", @miltonaut.

Comment: I see what you are saying. "We tried to get him coming to church" sounds awkward no matter how it is interpreted. @Colin Fine